# ng-repeat not showing data

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to display all Images of a specific property. each image can only belong to 1 property and 1 property can have multiple images.

I retrieving the Images table and property table separately. To assign each image to it's own property I' using the id as shown below.

```
<div ng-show="tab.isSet(3)">
      <h4>Images</h4>
      <img  ng-repeat="img in Images.imagePath| filter : {propertyId: pro.id}" ng-src="{{img}}"/>
</div>
```

Both tables are being retrieved fine. I'm using the property table to display other fields such as price, description etc. and is working fine. But when I'm trying to display the images, nothing is coming up.

No errors are shown as well!

I'm using ng-controller **propertyCtrl** in which I'm retrieving the table as an array object

```
$http.get("php/retrieveImages.php")
    .success(function(imageData) {
            $scope.Images = imageData;
            console.log(imageData);
        }).error(function() {
                $scope.Images="error in fetching data";
        });
```

The php:

```
<?php
require_once("connection.php");
$conn = connectToDb();

 $query = " SELECT
            img.imagePath,
            img.propertyId
            FROM 
            tbl_images AS img
            JOIN
            tbl_property AS pro
            ON(pro.id=img.propertyId)";  

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)
         or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($conn));


    $imageData = array(); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $imageData[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($imageData);
 ?>
```

The HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="propertyCtrl">

            <div ng-repeat="pro in property | filter:searchProp | orderBy:Select" >
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead class="thead-default">
                        <tr>
                            <th><span class='notbold'>Property Reference Number:</span> {{pro.id}}</th>
                            <th><span class='notbold'>Location:</span> {{pro.location}}</th>
                            <th><span class='notbold'>Property Type:</span> {{pro.propertyType}}</th>
                            <th><span class='notbold'>Commercial Or Residential:</span> {{pro.propertyType2}}</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                </table>
                <section ng-controller="TabController as tab" >
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(1)}"> 
                            <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Description</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(2)}">
                            <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Price</a>  
                        </li>
                        <li ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(3)}">
                            <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Images</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div ng-show="tab.isSet(1)">
                      <h4>Description</h4>
                      <blockquote>{{pro.description}}</blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)">
                      <h4>Price</h4>
                      <blockquote> € {{pro.price}}</blockquote>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-show="tab.isSet(3)">
                      <h4>Images</h4>
//ng-repeat not working!!!
 <img  ng-repeat="img in Images.imagePath| filter : {propertyId: pro.id}" ng-src="{{img}}"/>
   </div> 
 </div>
```

Logging the object array **Images**:

```
Array[4]
0:Object
imagePath:"Images/3D-printed-gun-Liberator-006.jpg"
propertyId:"8"
```

Logging the object array **Property**:

```
Array[6]
0:Object
$$hashKey: "object:9"
description:"A lovely flat near university.!!"
id:"8"
location:"Rabat"
locationId:"2"
price:"401.000"
propertyType:"Apartment"
propertyType2:"Commercial"
propertyTypeId:"1"
propertyTypeId2:"2"
```

**Can someone explain why it's is not showing the Images?**

**NOTE:** The path retrieved is good, as when inserted normally (`src ="Images/img.jpg"`) the image is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

After reading you, I guess that scope.Images is the array with all images, so you should use :

```
<img  ng-repeat="img in Images" ng-src="{{img.imagePath}}"/>
```

You want to iterate through array of images, and use the property of your object in ng-src.

Comment: img is the same as img.imagePath as I's defying with attribute to use in the ng-repeat. Yes, the scope Images is an array with all images but not all images belong to the same property, so that's why i used a filter to assigned each image to the correspondent property.

Answer (score 0):

I was filtering badly:

```
<img  ng-repeat="img in Images| filter :pro.id" ng-src="{{img.imagePath}}"/>
```

That solved the problem, filter by property id only!